# CSS / jQuery navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, navbar

I would like my navbar to have an animation when someone scrolls down past it and for the navbar to go to the top of the users screen.

I have absolutely no knowledge of jQuery, nor Javascript (if it is required).

In case you never got it, I have a nice navbar, and when a user scrolls past the navbar (so the navbar is around the top of the site, and when a user scrolls down the site, where the original navbar is no longer visible) the navbar (in a cool animation-type) to go to the top of the site;

if required, I will post a screenshot of our current navbar - I would appreciate tutorials or even codes to use on it, I would appreciate any answer, thank you all.

Comment: IS required the code with your try .... at least the htlm and CSS.... If you don't have knowledg about the theme search for `fixed navbar`

Comment: Sorry? I didn't quite understand what you meant, though ok, I'll search fixed navbar; any other suggestions?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8M2Vh/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very much like this is what you are looking for [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). You should be able to follow the template without changes to have it do what you want.

Comment: It's a javascript library that you include on your site along with a small piece of code in the html that makes the header stick.   [See this page](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)